# While loop doesn't catch When Passing 'A' into function I expect to stop rather than go through all possibilities

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import itertools   

def bruteForce3 (PasswordIn):  
    Password =''  
    while(Password != PasswordIn):

        bruteForceLen1(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen2(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen3(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen4(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen5(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen6(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen7(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen8(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen9(PasswordIn)
        bruteForceLen10(PasswordIn)

    print('DONE ',Password, " = ",PasswordIn)

def bruteForceLen1(PasswordIn):  
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',1)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen2(PasswordIn):        
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',2)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen3(PasswordIn):  
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',3)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen4(PasswordIn):  
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',4)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen5(PasswordIn):  
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',5)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen6(PasswordIn):
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',6)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen7(PasswordIn):  
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',7)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen8(PasswordIn):  
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',8)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen9(PasswordIn):  
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',9)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)

def bruteForceLen10(PasswordIn):  
    gen = itertools.combinations_with_replacement('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890',10)
    for Password in gen:
        Password = ''.join(Password)
        print(PasswordIn, Password)
```

Comment: Something happened here.

Comment: The idea is to Take in a string of no more than 10 character. Starting with 1 character password call functions below until we get a match. Sorry about formatting can't get indents to show when using 4 space?

Comment: There are several things wrong with your code. Relating specifically to your question: `Password` is initialised with `''` and it never changes its value while inside the `while` loop. So unless `PasswordIn` is also `''` the condition of your `while` loop will always evaluate to `True` and the loop will never exit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Password` is set to `''` in the `bruteForce3` function and never set again in that scope. The `Password` variables in the `xLenN` functions are local to those functions and have no impact on the test (`Password != PasswordIn`) that decides whether the `while` loop continues. The `while` loop, however, is set to go through all of the combinations in a single iteration. The `while` loop will not magically break when the `Password` name is set to a certain value. The decision to break the while loop based on the test is done when each iteration is completed (or `continue`d from).

Comment: So is the best solution to place the while loop within each sub function?